# Is there a solution to choose how my file is renamed if a file with the same name already exist?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint online when my flow moves the file (PDF, ZIP...) named "U000" in a folder where is a file with the same name it renames the file in "U0001".

How can I customize this to be renamed like "U000-Rev.1" or "U000_copy(1)" instead of "U0001"?

I know this is the default SharePoint behavior and there is no option for renaming format but maybe I can change or add a code in "definition.json" file from exported ZIP flow (or somewhere else).

(I'm not a software developer so any answer/idea is welcomed.)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using MS Flow to automate the file move?

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement to check the file name you just uploaded. If it contains (1) at the end of the name then rename the file. This is probably the least convoluted fast approach but it's not 100% robust.

You can add more logic or change the approach to make it fully robust but you can look into that after you've got something working imo, baby steps.